# Can't figure out how to display CoreData info

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I started a project to try and acquaint myself with CoreData, but I'm struggling to figure out how to update labels with the data once it's saved.

**The idea is:** Only when the app is first opened, an alert pops up asking for a username. That username is then stored to CoreData, and the app's homescreen contains a label that displays that username. But for some reason, I can't get the label's text to update.

**I'm getting an error in the "updateName" function.** On the line "var person = people[0]" I get the following:

> "Fatal error: Array index out of range."

I don't get why the 0 index wasn't already set as the alert's textfield. Any ideas?

```
class InitialViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var didRunBefore: Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("didRunBefore")    

@IBOutlet weak var userGreeting: UILabel!

var people = [NSManagedObject]()
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello!", message: "What's your name?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if !didRunBefore {
        getUserName()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "didRunBefore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")

    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        people = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}


func getUserName() {

    userGreeting.text = ""      
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let textField = self.alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField
        self.saveName(textField.text)
    }


    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    func updateName() {
        var person = people[0]
        if let userName1 = person.valueForKey("name") as? String {
            userGreeting.text = "Hey there, \(userName1)!"
        }
    }

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: updateName)

}


 func saveName(name: String) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!


    let entity1 =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity1!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


    person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")


    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

    people[0] = person
   }
  }
```

Comment: The error is because the completion handler for `presentViewController` is called after the viewDidAppear: method is called on the presented view controller, ie before your user has had a chance to enter a name and tap save.  Move the `updateName` code to the relevant action closures.